# Significato di "rinnegare" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Superino* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Nell’osteria di Placido Superino si mise a giocare alle carte col guardiacaccia. La posta, disse Menemio, era una miseria: Superino si giocava una dozzina di caramelle e l’altro una fetta di formaggio. A un certo punto litigarono. Col guardiacaccia non poteva non succedere e anche Superino si accendeva in un niente e aveva la fiammata lunga. Superino lo accusò di **aver rinnegato**, il guardiacaccia naturalmente negò e in un attimo si trovarono presi per i denti. Qualcuno cercò di metter pace, suggerí di annullare quella mano e rifarla, ma senza troppo impegno, d’altronde i due non erano tipi da accettare i consigli di terzi. Superino insistette sul **rinnego** e il guardiacaccia per meglio difendersi disse che quel dannato ragazzo dai capelli rossi lo truffava nei punti approfittando della sua maggior confidenza con le cifre.

Ho cercato il verbo "rinnegare" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI16/GDLI_16_ocr_565.pdf) (continua [qui](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI16/GDLI_16_ocr_566.pdf)), ma non riesco a capire cosa possa significare nel passaggio sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Credo che qui sia usato nel senso di "negare con forza" (di aver barato a carte?)

Comment: Bisognerebbe sapere quale gioco di carte. Nel tressette, è obbligatorio rispondere al seme giocato per primo: se il primo giocatore cala il tre di bastoni, il secondo deve calare bastoni, se ne ha, fosse anche l'asso. La mia impressione è che dalle parti di Fenoglio si dica *rinnegare* per *rifiutare* (adoperato in altre regioni), cioè calare una carta di seme diverso violando la regola.

Comment: @egreg: Nel racconto non si menziona di quale gioco si tratti.